# A result related to the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H\trianglelefteq G$ and $\tilde{K}\leq G/H$, where $\tilde{K}\simeq K/H$, for some $K\leq G$ such that $H\subset K$. Prove that $\tilde{K}\trianglelefteq G/H$ if and only if $K\trianglelefteq G$. Note here that $"\trianglelefteq"$ is being used to denote a normal subgroup and $"\leq"$ is being used to denote a subgroup.

In my original attempt at proving this problem, I showed that $K/H \trianglelefteq G/H$ if and only if $K\trianglelefteq G$. I then concluded, incorrectly, that $\tilde{K} \trianglelefteq G/H$ if and only if $K\trianglelefteq G$. Realizing that this is the incorrect way to approach the problem, I am really stuck on how the desired result should be proven.

Comment: By $\simeq$ do you really mean $=$? Otherwise this is false: let $H$ be the trivial subgroup, so that the statement becomes "if $K$ and $K'$ are isomorphic subgroups of $G$, and $K$ is normal, then $K'$ is normal". This is false since, for example, $D_8$ contains both normal and non-normal subgroups of order $2$.

Comment: Note that $\overline{K}$ is **equal** to $K/H$ for some $K\leq G$. Not sure what your issue here is, in light of that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin While every subgroup of $G/H$ is of that form, the subgroup $K$ appearing in the assumed isomorphism(?) $\overline{K} \cong K/H$ need not be the desired object -- as long as I'm not misunderstanding the meaning of $\simeq$ here, this claim is actually false.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments. I'm reaching out to the instructor and checking if there was a typo.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: Yes, I understand what you said; and I understand that this would be the literal interpretation if the symbol used is meant to represent isomorphism (though that is usually $\cong$ rather than $\simeq$). The reason that is almost certainly not what was intended is that in that case there is absolutely no reason to use the letter $K$ with decoration for the subgroup in the quotient and the “quasi-corresponding” subgroup in $G$ be denoted likewise by $K$.